# Count non null elements in an array of lists

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I couldn't find this anywhere else.
I've an array of lists:

```
public List<xmldata>[] XMLArrayList = new List<xmldata>[9999];
```

To initialize and insert a list into each position, i do the following:

```
for(int m=0; m< XList.XMLArrayList.Count(); m++)
{
    XList.XMLArrayList[m] = new List<xmldata>();
}
```

But i would like to count how many elements there aren't null.
EX: Positions 0 to 5 have a List on them. But other positions not.

Tried a linq approach:

```
int count = XList.XMLArrayList.Count(x => x != null);
```

But it returns me the array size (9999). How can i count the non null elements on an array of lists ?
Ps: Already tried Dictionary and And List of List - this approach works best for achieving what i need.

Thanks.

Comment: If you initialize all the array positions to new list then none of them are null and you should get the length of the array.

Comment: @GediminasMasaitis In this case it is.

Comment: Maybe you want *empty* elements, not *null* elements?

Comment: Yeah - i do initialize all of 'em. But how can i find on all initialized positions those who contains a xmldata object ?

Comment: @Gusman yeah - empty elements. You got what i need.

Comment: @juharr Indeed it is, my bad.

Comment: The Alexander's solution is the right one, there is a big difference between an empty list and a null list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
int count = XList.XMLArrayList.Count(x => x.Count()>0);
```

Comment: Exactly  ! WOrked as expected. Thanks.

Comment: Since these are lists you can use the `Count` property instead of the `Count()` extension method.

Comment: This is slightly cleaner: `XList.XMLArrayList.Count(c => c.Any());`

Comment: Checking for non-empty collections is more ideomatically done using `enumeration.Any()` rather than `enumeration.Count() > 0`. it is also faster (O(1) vs O(n)). if Count() is evaluated on a heavy sql query it'll be very expensive. `Any()` will just check if enumerating yields an element and then return, regardless of the size of the enumeration.

Comment: @kai, Since these are lists the `Count()` extenstion method will just end up returning the `Count` property value which is O(1).

Comment: @juharr that's true I guess, I'd still argue it's more correct, both from a semantic and from a maintainability point of view to use `Any` when checking for emptyness, even if the practical difference is negligible in this case (good habits and all that)

Answer (score 0):

you can also do this

```
XList.XMLArrayList.Where(x => x.Any()).Count();
```

Comment: this won't compile, you're using XMLArrayList as a method.